# Filtering a CSV where the system date format and file date formats differ

Tags: date, powershell, csv

I have a large source CSV file with 3 example rows as below

```
0000000000254000,19/02/2014,"zzzzzzz","close","BIL","5378874","125.00",
0000000000254000,19/12/2013,"zzzzzzz","close","BIL","5378874","125.00",
0000000000254000,19/08/2013,"zzzzzzz","close","BIL","5378874","125.00",
```

I want to remove all lines that are < 10 days old i.e. where today() - above date column <10 and am close with the following script based on the kind donations of others on this site:

```
get-content C:\temp\date2.csv | where {
  [date] ($_.split(','))[1] -lt (get-date).date.adddays(-10)
} | set-content "C:\temp\newdate.txt"
```

It works if I align the dates in the file with the powershell system date format but could anyone help with how I can do this within the above simple script please?

I've tried this at the start but failed miserably:

```
(Get-Culture).DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern="dd/MM/yyyy"
```

Comment: When you say "failed miserably", what actually happened? Errors, incorrect rows being returned?

Comment: Sorry - my export file was empty

Comment: If I run the script above without the output statement, I get errors.
"Unable to find type [date]: make sure that the assembly containing this type is loaded."

Comment: If you change the date format in the file to 01/01/2014 00:00:00 and change [date] to [datetime] it works. I'm trying to understand how to do it by date only and stuck. Thank-you for your support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Import-Csv C:\temp\date2.csv -Header c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7 | 
where { [datetime]::ParseExact($_.c2, "dd/MM/yyyy", $null) -lt (get-date).date.adddays(-10)} | 
Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation "C:\temp\newdate.txt"
```

The *-Header* gives names to columns and you can change that to whatever you want as long as you amend `$_.c2` on line 2 accordingly.

Comment: This is great and resolves the problem, thank-you for taking the time to help me out - I genuinely much appreciate it.